# How to change the Text of a Button in One form with a Button click of another Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two **forms**. In the first form there is a **button** with the text "Log In". By clicking this **button** I will open another form where I will be able to log in using username and password. Then there is a **button** "Proceed", it will verify the username and password and then close the 2nd form. Then it will change the text of the "Log In" **Button** in the first form to "Welcome, " + username.

Everything works just fine, but I can't change the text of the **button** in the 1st form. I understand that I need to refresh the **Form1** after closing the **Form2**. But I was unable to do it.

Comment: "but I can't change the text of the button in the 1st form". is this because you cannot access the button of form1 from form2? You could change it after you finishes with form2 and returns to form1, no?

Comment: Yes, I can't access the button from form2. I want to show the username right after closing form2. If I change it after returning to form1, then I would need to use another button or click or something, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way, I have something on `form2` which records the text I entered.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {
    public string InputText = ""; //use this to record whatever is inputed in the Form2 by the user
    //somewhere else in the code
    public void foo(){ //this may be closing event or button pressed event
        InputText = textBoxInForm2.Text; //record the input from `form2` textbox
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; //mark as ok
    }

    //This is exactly the foo above, but just in case you wonder how the event FormClosing look like:
    //Add this event handler on your Form2
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        InputText = textBoxInForm2.Text; //record the input from `form2` textbox
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Then in your `form1`, you could open `form2` with `ShowDialog`. Then if the dialog results the way you want, something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(); //this must be declared in form1
        if (form2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
            textBoxInForm1.Text = form2.InputText; //grab the input text
        }
    }
}
```

Then update the `textBoxInForm1` with whatever value from `form2`

Edit: in the example I gave, the `form2` is created in the `form1` constrcution. This obviously may not be always true. But the example is shown to emphasize that the `form2` must be within `form1` domain to access. In this case, being an object declared in its `constructor`. You can place where your `form2` is created as per necessary: as a `property` of `Form1` class, inside one of the `Form1` method, etc

Comment: Let me give this a try, I will let you know if this helps my purpose. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Where should I write the if condition in form1? Inside with method?

Comment: yes, one way is In the method where you call `Form2`. This is because `form2.ShowDialog` will block your app until you produce dialog result from `form2`. The `DialogResult` should either be produced by closing the form (as shown in my example) or by confirmation method (such as button pressed) in form 2.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad to know that! ;) the idea here is to have a public variable and to declare the child form (form2) from the parent form (form1). That way, form1 can easily get what is in the form2. What I show is not the only way doing that... it is just my preferred way. =)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to return in your form1.

You should create another form class and design it as per your requirement.
Then activate this form to accomplish your task.